# Update Data return Cannot insert duplicate key row in object

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm working with Entity Framework and the structure for my DB is something like this:

An user have a collections of subscribers, so...

Subscriber:
   Name
   UserId
   User (to navigate on user object)

if I get the subscriber without the user, I modify the "name" and commit the changes and all works fine, but if I get the subscriber with the user instanciated, in the CommitAndRefreshChanges, throws me:
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.User' with unique index 'PK_Email'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated

but I don't change anything for user... what I'm doing wrong?

To get the subscriber I run on the repository:

```
 RegistrationModuleDataModelContainer context = UnitOfWork as RegistrationModuleDataModelContainer;

 Subscriber subscriber = (from s in context.Subscribers.Include(it=>it.User)
                                where s.IdSubscriber == idSubscriber
                                select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

To modify the data use the next code:

```
Subscriber subscriber = this.GetSubscriberWithUser(idSubscriber);
        subscriber.FirstName = FirstName;
        subscriber.LastName = LastName;

         //Condition with subscriber.User.x
              subscriber.Email = Email;

        _subscriberRepository.Modify(subscriber);

        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = _subscriberRepository.UnitOfWork;
        unitOfWork.CommitAndRefreshChanges();
```

If I erase the condition, fails anyway, the problem is when I load the subscriber with the user, if I load the subscriber only, the commit works.

Thanks!

Comment: You are most probably modifying detached entity, don't you? You just forgot to post your data modification code so how should we know what is wrong in your application?

Comment: Tank Lidislav for the answer, I just add the modification code.